# I can't unlock my phone!

Tags: cipher, visual, steganography

This puzzle is based on [A Strange Poster](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62182/a-strange-poster) by [Synj](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/46716/synj). Looking at their puzzle (specifically hints 1-3) will give away the first few steps of this puzzle.

---

### Can you help unlock my phone by solving the cipher?

I was on my way home from math class when my music stopped playing. When I looked at my phone I saw this: [image: Album Artwork Visual]

Now my phone is locked and just the grid appears. I think in order to unlock my phone I need to fill in the second half of the grid. The question is with what?

Since there are several solutions to this puzzle, I'll ask for 3 things.

1. The second half of the grid filled in
2. I bet my math teacher is behind this. What is his name?
3. What is my name?

Hint 1:

> I saw my math teacher today. He is definitely behind this. He told me that I should talk to the cafeteria staff for more hints.

Hint 2:

> I talked to the cafeteria staff. Apparently a shipment of meat has gone missing. They told me that five boxes of hamburgers, nine packages of Bacon, and one box of hotdogs are gone. I doubt my math teacher is behind this but I still think it’s a clue.

Comment: Have you [defragged your phone](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_O-HJgvcZDok/S1LS6zCEv9I/AAAAAAAAC3I/NmZ8qzlgR6c/s800/defraging-tool.png) recently?

Comment: @Chowzen - LOL, only children of the 90s might understand that reference :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Using [Peter Saville's color codes](https://wharferj.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/savilles-colour-code.jpg), we can translate the colors at the top to:
> LDFQAGBSTOPDABFBFQGBEALDI
> FTRAPILMDFIAXHH
> EDWARDTTFLOBALRZFCBG
> Note: Some or all the 'A' characters may actually be 'K', and the same goes for 'B' and 'V', as the line that separates those letters is ambiguous here. The letters A-I could also be the numbers 1-9.
> ROT1-ROT25 gave me nothing useful.
> I'm also suspecting either your name or your teacher's name is Edward.

Comment: Good start. You've translated most of the grid correctly. The mistakes will not stop you from continuing